# Format SD card after playing with fdisk (No card reader)

Tags: external-sd, partitions, command-line, formatting, busybox

After playing with partitioning using FDISK (from busybox) i finished and now i want to format it back to whatever is usable under Android.

Using same FDISK via Android console i deleted all partitions, made a clean DOS partition table, made a new partition and changed its type to b (Win95 FAT32).

I got no microSD adapter to read the card from my linux PC and format it there.
What should i do to format it into a usable condition?

Comment: As you wrote: format it? Just creating a partition does not yet make it usable. I cannot look it up from here currently, but there should be a `mkfs.vfat` in `/system/sbin` for this.

Comment: @izzy I know a partition needs a format. Thanks for answer even through its in comment.

Comment: If it solved your issue, I can make it an answer with some more details :) And sorry for the second sentence -- must have missed that in your questions last paragraph, my bad...

Comment: @Izzy I am getting `mkfs.vfat: lseek: Value too large for defined data type` everytime.

Comment: How big is the card, and what parameters did you use? That error usually indicates you're breaking some limit (comes e.g. when you try to extend a file beyond 2 GB on FAT and the like). Or, according to [this XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=26030990), you might need a different version of BusyBox (see post #12).

Comment: #Izzy I had a 4 gb card. Thanks, the busybox you provided actualy helped.

Comment: Glad to read! I summed up the comments and made it an answer. Would be nice if you could accept it (by clicking the checkmark next to it) -- which makes it easier for other searchers to identify "issues with a working solution". Further good luck, and see you next time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>Summing up from the comments:</sup>

With BusyBox, Android provides tools for formatting from the command line. In your case, this would be `/system/sbin/mkfs.vfat`. This is reported to sometimes throw an error like:

```
mkfs.vfat: lseek: Value too large for defined data type
```

According to [this XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=26030990), this is the fault of Busybox. Using a different version (as reported in post #12 of that thread) should solve the issue -- and did it in your case, luckily.

Answer (score 3):

Android has built-in formatting capabilities that are usually available via `Settings -> Storage -> Format SD card` (or something similar depending on the device you use).